# Drawing trees on small number of lines in 2D and 3D

Tags: graph-theory, trees, extremal-graph-theory

> **Problem.** Given a tree do we need fewer lines in 3D than in 2D in order to draw it straightline and crossing-free?

(Asked 01.10.2016 by Alexander Wolff on [page 20](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?vol=1&page=20) of [Volume 1](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=1) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/view.php)).

**Clarification.** For a given finite simple graph $G$ by $\rho^1_2(G)$ (resp. $\rho^1_3(G)$) we denote the minimal number of straight lines needed to *cover* all edges in a straight-line crossing-free drawing of the graph $G$ in 2D (resp. 3D). We are asking for a tree $T$ such that $\rho^1_3(T)<\rho^1_2(T)$.

The problem was originally asked 11.06.2016 by [Oleg Verbitsky](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01196).

Comment: A tree $T$ on $n$ vertices can be drawn in the plane with $n-1$ noncrossing segments, exactly the number of edges of $T$. Maybe you didn't mean to restrict your question to trees? (The title and the body are different.)

Comment: I think the OP considers 2 line segments to only count as 1 if they lie on the same line and are adjacent.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that you need the same number of lines in 2D and 3D to draw the trees. The trick to proving it is find a mapping from embeddings in 3D to embedding in 2D that preserves the number of lines used.

Comment: @Mosquite: Thanks, you must be right in your interpretation.

Comment: If two edges in a drawing lie on the same line but have intermediate edges between them that _don't_, are they considered to be part of the same line or not? (i.e., are all edges on a 'line', for counting purposes, contiguous or not?) If the goal is to actually minimize the number of line _segments_ (and so noncontiguous edges can't count as part of the same line) then I'm pretty sure any 3d drawing can actually be translated directly down to 2d.

Comment: (To be more specific: imagine a tree with a 'root' node of degree 4, leading to 4 internal nodes each of (total) degree three, with the two non-root edges on each of those 4 internal nodes leading to a leaf. Then the number of line segments needed is clearly six: the four edges from the root can be drawn on 2 lines, and for each of those lines we can put one additional segment on each end, but this leaves 4 more isolated segments to be drawn. OTOH,it's obviously possible to build a drawing of this tree that can be covered by 4 lines by aligning those isolated segments properly with each other)

Comment: Putting it in pictures: does the tree in http://i.imgur.com/vj9a0RE.png count as 6 lines or 4?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki As 4. See more in my [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263667/drawing-trees-on-small-number-of-lines-in-2d-and-3d/#comment651810_263678) to Mosquite’s answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure how to prove this, but here is my candidate for an embedding in 2D that minimizes the number of lines used:

For each node in the tree if it has an even number of edges, $2e$ then embed pairs of edges on the same line (i.e. put the edge $\frac{\pi}{e}$ radians apart) so that the node uses $e$ lines in total; if the node has an odd number of edges, $2e + 1$ then do the same, but have one edge be on its own line (put it at some angle not used by the other edges) to use $e+1$ lines in total. This process is possible by making the embedding spread out enough that there is no crossing.

I believe that you cannot do better than this because an edge can be on the same line of at most one incident edge. Furthermore I believe you cannot do better in 3D as well for the same reason.

Comment: The drawing of the tree may be very bent, allowing to a straight line to cover many edges. We even don’t know whether exists there a constant $c>0$ such that any tree with $n$ vertices admits a planar (straight-line crossing-free) drawing which can be covered by  $c\sqrt{n}$ straight lines.

Comment: My embedding allows lines to cover more than 2 edges. The process is only concerned with how to embed the edges at a per node level. I would be interested to see a tree that can be drawn with less lines than my embedding, unless I misunderstand the problem (i.e. the OP may suppose that the lines can have gaps in the edges they cover).

Comment: Yes, they can have the gaps. The minimum number $segm(G)$ of segments without gaps in a planar drawing of a graph $G$ is a subject of another problem (see, for instance, references [14] and [19] in the paper [1] from the question).  Clearly, $segm(G)\ge \rho^1_2(G)$ for any planar graph. It turns out, however, that $segm(G) = O(\rho^1_2(G)^2) $ for any connected planar graph $G$. You can read a proof of this result and more about relations between $segm(G)$ and $\rho^1_2(G)$ is Section 3.2 of paper [1].

Comment: Concerning trees, it is known (see again [14] or [19]) that ignoring additive constants $segm(T)$ is equal to a half of the number of vertices of $T$ of odd degree.